# Passing a pointer from function C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

I have a text file in which I read into a 2D array like this:

```
 153 62 328 71 0.998263 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 160 58 335 67 0.99699 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 192 43 362 53 0.998 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 224 34 389 45 0.994047 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I only need the first four columns. I create a function that stores the numbers into a 2D array. I want to pass a pointer from that function to main that points to the address of the first element of the array.

In the main function I try to increment the pointer index to get the values from the array again but I am unable to get the correct numbers. Clearly my understanding with 2D array pointers is limited and I'd appreciate any help.

My code is here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int lines_in_pos_obj_file(int i = 0)
{
    string pos_obj_file_line;

    ifstream pos_obj_file("correspondencePOS000_sphere.txt");
    if(pos_obj_file.is_open())
    {
        while(getline(pos_obj_file, pos_obj_file_line))
        {
            i++;
        }
    }

    else cout << "Unable to open file";
    return(i);
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int *get_pos_obj_positions(int k)
{
    int pos_obj_positions[k][4];
    int i = 1;

    string pos_obj_file_line;

    ifstream pos_obj_file("correspondencePOS000_sphere.txt");
    if(pos_obj_file.is_open())
    {

        pos_obj_file >> pos_obj_positions[0][0] >> pos_obj_positions[0][1] >> pos_obj_positions[0][2] >> pos_obj_positions[0][3];

        while(getline(pos_obj_file, pos_obj_file_line))
        {

            pos_obj_file >> pos_obj_positions[i][0] >> pos_obj_positions[i][1] >> pos_obj_positions[i][2] >> pos_obj_positions[i][3];

            i++;
        }
    }

    else cout << "Unable to open file";

    int (*pos_obj_pointer)[4] = &pos_obj_positions[0];
    return(pos_obj_pointer[0]);
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main()
{   
    int pos_obj_lines;
    int *pos_obj_positions; 

    pos_obj_lines = lines_in_pos_obj_file(0);
    pos_obj_positions = get_pos_obj_positions(pos_obj_lines);

    for(int l = 0; l < pos_obj_lines; l++)
    {
    cout << pos_obj_positions[l] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
153
0
1670302324
32656
-1690506736
1
3
0
6
0
1672415896
32656
```

Comment: Consider using vectors of vectors, e.g. `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`; or use a plain array (or a plain vector) and access `a[W*i+j]` instead of `t[i][j]` .... And please indent your code so that it fits (no more than 72 characters wide).

Answer (score 3):

You are returning a pointer to a local variable `int pos_obj_positions[k][4];`. The variable is destroyed when function finishes.

Allocate the array in `main` and pass it to the `get_obj_pos_positions` function.

Comment: And most compilers would warn you against that if you enable all warnings (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g`)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you pass the 2D array as input parameter rather than return value. Or better still use vector.

```
void get_pos_obj_positions(int k, int pos_obj_positions[][4])
{
    int i = 1;

    string pos_obj_file_line;

    ifstream pos_obj_file("correspondencePOS000_sphere.txt");
    if(pos_obj_file.is_open())
    {

        pos_obj_file >> pos_obj_positions[0][0] >> pos_obj_positions[0][1] >> pos_obj_positions[0][2] >> pos_obj_positions[0][3];

        while(getline(pos_obj_file, pos_obj_file_line))
        {

            pos_obj_file >> pos_obj_positions[i][0] >> pos_obj_positions[i][1] >> pos_obj_positions[i][2] >> pos_obj_positions[i][3];

            i++;
        }
    }

    else cout << "Unable to open file";
}

int main()
{   
    int pos_obj_lines;
    int **pos_obj_positions; 

    pos_obj_lines = lines_in_pos_obj_file(0);

    pos_obj_positions = new int[ pos_obj_lines ];
    for ( int I = 0; I < pos_obj_lines; I++ ) {
      pos_obj_positions = new int[4];
    }
    get_pos_obj_positions(pos_obj_lines,pos_obj_positions);

    return 0;
}
```